# Remote not using hosts file from server

Tags: hosts

I am using a hosts file on an `Ubuntu Server` where is written all the pairs `IP domain names`.
The remote computers (all of them with Windows OS) are connected to the server on the same network and they are configured correctly saying that they have to use it as a DNS server.

So the trouble is that when I try to browse to one of those websites it doesn't work unless I write it on the remote computer hosts file, so I see it is not using the server's hosts file.
What should I do?

EDIT 1: It seems that /etc/host.conf is well written:

`order hosts,bind
multi on`

/etc/nsswitch.conf too:
`hosts:  files dns`

and  /etc/resolv.conf it is itself:
`nameserver 127.0.0.1`

Comment: A glaring omission from this question is why you think that there's a DNS server at that IP address, and what you think that that DNS server is serving up.  Please fix this.

Comment: I believe there is a misunderstanding here.  The /etc/hosts file on a unix machine is only for that unix machine.  DNS stands for Domain Name System, which is a service that runs on some server.  You need a DNS server running somewhere.  The DNS server has its own data files.  The information you have in /etc/hosts would need to be in the DNS server data files.